# Why can't I equate thermal current at the point?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

so I was solving this question. And yes this might look like a homework question but I am not asking for a solution, I am asking why equating the thermal current at the point P is wrong.
The question is as follows :

A metal rod AB of length 10x has one of its ends, A in ice at zero degrees celsius and the other end B in water at 100 degrees celsius. If a point P on the rod is maintained at 400 degrees celsius such that the amount of ice that melts per unit time at A and the amount of water that evaporates per unit time at B is the same. If the point P is at a distance lx from the end A then find "l" assuming no heat loss to the surroundings.

Like why can't I just equate the thermal current that is flowing in the rod from P to A and P to B ? shouldn't the following equation be valid :
$\displaystyle{\frac{KA(400-0)}{lx} = \frac{KA(400-100)}{(10-l)x}}$

Assuming A to be the Area of cross section of the rod and K to be its coefficient of thermal conductivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question tells you that equal "amounts" (numbers of moles, presumably) of ice melt and water evaporate. The molar latent heat of melting of ice is much less than the molar latent heat of evaporation of water! You will need to amend your equation to take this into account.

Comment: I should have been more clear, equal amounts refers to equal mass of ice and water melt and evaporate respectively.

Comment: Equal masses implies equal amounts and vice versa, since 1 mole of $\text{H}_2\text{O}$ has a mass of 18.0 g whether it's ice, water or steam. So the ratio of molar latent heats will be the same as the ratio of specific latent heats, and it is just the ratio that should appear in your equation.

Comment: I got the equations from Fourier's law $\frac{dQ}{dt} =- KA \frac{dT}{dx}$ so how does the molar latent heat affect these equations ?

Comment: You need a greater rate of flow of heat to evaporate a kg of water per unit time than you need to melt a kg of ice per unit time! The ratio of heat flow rates needed is the ratio of the specific (or the molar) latent heats. That's easy to see, is it not?